# Не видны объекты из .xaml в partial class

Tags: c#, wpf

Пробую писать программу на WPF (тел. книга), весь исходный код у меня в классе `MainWindow`. Хотелось бы создать отдельный файл `.cs` и с использованием `partial class` писать код там, потому что иначе получается очень много кода, и он трудно читается.

Я создал файл `.cs`, подключил нужные пространства имен, сделал `public partial class MainWindow`, однако в этом частичном классе совершенно не видно объектов, генерируемых в `.xaml`: например, `<TextBox x:Name="displayPhone" .... />` по имени `displayPhone` VS не видит.

Как настроить в этом случае частичный класс в другом файле внутри проекта?

Код внутри оригинального `MainWindow`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
namespace calc
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public void NumButtonClick(object sender) 
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            string Number = b.Content.ToString();
            if (CheckDisplayZeroOnly()) displayPhone.Clear();
            displayPhone.Text += Number;
            if (!CheckDisplayLimitLength())
            {
                displayPhone.Text = displayPhone.Text.Substring(0, displayPhone.Text.Length - 1);
            }
        }
```

В этом коде есть нормальный доступ к элементу, описанному в *.xaml*, по имени `displayPhone`. Но если я в проекте создам файл именем `PhoneLogic` и впишу такой код, то `displayPhone` уже не доступен в этом файле:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using calc;
namespace calc
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public void Foo()
        {
            displayPhone // не доступен
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем у вас там using calc; ? Вы ведь вроде бы работаете в этом пространстве имен и так.

Comment: Я его вставил в надежде на лучшее, но хоть с ним, хоть без него, не идет и все

Comment: Сорри, исправил, с калькулятором попутал. Просто делаю два разных проекта для тренировки калькулятор и тел. книгу

Comment: _.xaml_-файл бы ещё в вопрос добавить для полноты картины. Остальной код в `MainWindow` не имеет отношения к вопросу?

Comment: У меня, кстати, с удалением строк `if (CheckDisplayZeroOnly()) displayPhone.Clear();` и `if (!CheckDisplayLimitLength())` и добавлением `private TextBox displayPhone;` в `MainWindow.xaml.cs` код компилируется.

Comment: @Regent - TC попутал два проекта, о чем и написал выше, вопрос надо просто закрывать.

Comment: @Mirdin я так понял, что "попутал" при оформлении вопроса, а не в самом коде проекта.

Comment: @Regent, сорри за путаницу. Но тогда автор "что то не договаривает", пример выше рабочий.

Comment: @PolyakovSergey, сделайте ребилд проекта и выложите в вопрос ошибки которые вам выдало, а так же xaml.

Comment: Спасибо, Mirdin, сделал ребилд, заработало